# Using a function query from Solr

Tags: ajax, rest, solr, indexing

I'm trying to calculate the tf*idf of a term in my index.
Following Yonik's post from http://yonik.com/posts/solr-relevancy-function-queries/ I tried
`http://localhost:8080/solr/select/?fl=score,id&defType=func&q=mul(tf(texto_completo,bug),idf(texto,bug))`
(where texto_completo is the field, and 'bug' is the term) without much success. The response was:

> error 400: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (null).

I went ahead and looked at this answer /a/13477887 so I tried to do a simpler function query:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select/?q={!func}docFreq(texto_completo,bug)
```

And yet, I got the same error.
What is my syntax lacking to work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this not working:

```
q={!func}docFreq(texto_completo,bug)
```

use all lower-case `docfreq`:

```
q={!func}docfreq(texto_completo,bug)
```

I just tried:

```
q={!func}mul(tf(name,movie),idf(name,movie))
```

in Solr 4.2.1 and it is working fine. My field name is `name` (Text type) and term I am looking for is `movie`.

**UPDATE**: You need at least Solr 4.0 to use these. See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Relevance_Functions

Comment: I am using Solr 3.6, does that make a difference?